# Regex to capture log that is not parsed with multi-line option

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to filter out `transfer.sh` URLs using regex. The catch here is that the log isn't parsed with "multiline" option but instead as a whole log.

I have the regex that I designed available here: https://regex101.com/r/vx94RA/2

I want the output to be:

```
https://transfer.sh/JKdZg/pkbuild.txt
https://transfer.sh/nfs2l/var_log.tar
https://transfer.sh/PsafD3/systemd_journal.txt
```

But, the regex that I designed is able to capture only the first entry

Comment: You should set the 'global' flag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is returning after the first match. Enable the global flag.

https://regex101.com/r/vx94RA/3